# pybinding cannot import name allow_rasterization

Tags: python, pybinding

I just install pybinding and I'm trying to run the first example that is proposed in the documentation of this library.

```
import pybinding as pb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pybinding as pb

d = 0.2  # [nm] unit cell length
t = 1    # [eV] hopping energy

# create a simple 2D lattice with vectors a1 and a2
lattice = pb.Lattice(a1=[d, 0], a2=[0, d])
lattice.add_sublattices(
    ('A', [0, 0])  # add an atom called 'A' at position [0, 0]
)
lattice.add_hoppings(
    # (relative_index, from_sublattice, to_sublattice, energy)
    ([0, 1], 'A', 'A', t),
    ([1, 0], 'A', 'A', t)
)

lattice.plot()
plt.show()
```

I have already installed what is required in the documentation (for Windows OS) and the sicrpt run pretty well until it has to do the lattice.plot() throwing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 25, in <module>
    lattice.plot()
  File "C:\xampp7\Python\lib\site-packages\pybinding\lattice.py", line 463, in plot
    axes=axes))
  File "C:\xampp7\Python\lib\site-packages\pybinding\results.py", line 598, in plot
    plot_sites(self.positions, self.sublattices, **props['site'])
  File "C:\xampp7\Python\lib\site-packages\pybinding\system.py", line 285, in plot_sites
    from pybinding.support.collections import CircleCollection
  File "C:\xampp7\Python\lib\site-packages\pybinding\support\collections.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib.collections import Collection, allow_rasterization
ImportError: cannot import name 'allow_rasterization'
```

I have already check and matplotlib is correctly installed (I try some plots recommended in the documentation of matplotlib and worked pretty well). Also a looked for the file collections.py in the pybinding library and the mistake is in the second line

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import Collection, allow_rasterization
```

And looking at collections.py of the matplolib and searching for 'allow_rasterization' I found the duplicated 6 time the following function

```
@artist.allow_rasterization
def draw(self, renderer):
```

I am pretty new at python so I'm don't know if I'm looking at what I should. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled version 2.2.2 of `matplotlib` and installed version 1.1.2 of `marplotlib`.
I am now able to do `put.show()`

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue. I'm using Linux and the package ***pybinding*** are installed on

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pybinding/support/
```

You can correct the error changing the import modules of `allow_rasterization` module, changing the file *colletion.py*

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pybinding/support/colletion.py
```

the firsts lines from

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import Collection, allow_rasterization
```

to

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import Collection
from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
```

You can correct the plot issue related to previous versions on `matplotlib 1.1.2`, because now the pybinding packages use `matplotlib 2.2.2`.

Comment: I got the same issue too, but with the fix you propose the kernel refuse to do the plot. Do you have to do something else or just change thoses lines?

Answer (score 1):

go into the file "C:\xampp7\Python\lib\site-packages\pybinding\support\collections.py" and modify the command line as:
"from matplotlib.collections import Collection#, allow_rasterization
from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization"

Comment: What if he uses linux?

Comment: just read the compiling info, and track down the source of this error. it's just someone revised the codes inconsistently.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the directory:
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pybinding/support

In the file: **collections.py**
change line 2:

```
from matplotlib.collections import Collection, allow_rasterization
```

to

```
from matplotlib.collections import Collection 
from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
```